# Password Confirm not Comparing with Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, passwords

I'm not sure how to validate the confirm password element, this code seems to work, but the validates confirmation of password doesn't seem to compare the passwords as expected, just need a hand getting used to Rails 4's new ways.

Sign Up View:
    
        Sign Up

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <% if @user.errors.any? %>
            <div class="error_messages">
                <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
                <ul>
                    <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
                        <li><%= message %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", autofocus: "", required: "", placeholder: "Email address" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", required: "", placeholder: "Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", required: "", placeholder: "Confirm Password" %><br/>
        <p class="button"><%= submit_tag "Register", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.create(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end
    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :passord_confirmation, :salt, :encrypted_password)
    end
end
```

Users Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :password
    before_save :encrypt_password

    validates_presence_of :password, on: :create
    validates :password, confirmation: :true
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    def self.authenticate(email, password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
            user
        else
            nil
        end
    end
    private
    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the problem and what is your question?

Comment: The problem is that rails 4 isn't confirming the password by comparing the two passwords. The question is how do you fix it?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  What does "isn't confirming" mean?  What specific action happens, what is the actual result of that action _in concrete terms_, and what was the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model's password confirmation may be off, unless you have your own private method `confirmation`

Try changing your model from `validates :password, confirmation: :true` to `validates_confirmation_of :password`

The [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_confirmation_of) has some examples as well.

Comment: I had this earlier, but seen that you can also do it the way that I have done it, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Can you try the above change and add `validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, if: :password_changed?`?

Comment: That just give me an error like so when trying to create: undefined method `password_changed?' for #<User:0x007f8d34731fe0>

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the password and password_confirmation accessible. For example:

```
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation

validates :password, :presence     => true,
                     :confirmation => true
```

Try adding that, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It's Rails 4, attribute_accessible is no longer valid. Now uses strong params.